# Having an issue with classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to convert a function I made for computing a single "damage" output and I don't understand where I'm going wrong. As a function it processes my methods normally but when made into a class I receive a global name not found. Also, I'm thinking that my **init** is correct but I may be wrong.

```
import random

class Damage(object):
    """Represents 1 single damage value"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor initializes objects attributes. stats."""
        ### I need to initialize my stats from a different class since they
        ### are not a constant. self._statList is a dictionary that will be
        ### imported.
        self._statList = {"strength":100, "hitStat":90, "eBlockchance":10, \
                          "critStat":15, "defense":0}
        self._strength = self._statList["strength"]
        self._hitStat  = self._statList["hitStat"]
        self._eBlockchance = self._statList["eBlockchance"]
        self._defense = self._statList["defense"]
        self._critStat = self._statList["critStat"]

    def __str__(self):
        """Returns string representation of the damage"""
        self._base = self._strength - self._defense
        self._damage = random.randint(self._base/2, self._base)
        ### I have no idea why this isn't running my methods below.
        ### NameError: global name 'hitChance' is not defined.
        if hitChance() == True:
            return "Miss"
        else:
            if enemyBlock() == True:
                return "Block"
            else:
                if critChance() == True:
                    return str(self._damage*2) + "CRITICAL"
                else:
                    return str(self._damage)

    def critChance(self):
        self._chance = random.randint(1,100)
        if self._chance <= self._critStat:
            return True

    def enemyBlock(self):
        self._chance = random.randint(1,100)
        if self._chance <= self._eBlockchance:
            return True

    def hitChance(self):
        self._chance = random.randint(1,100)
        if self._chance > self._hitStat:
            return True
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback, and not have us guess as to what name you might be missing.

Comment: where is the problem? on which method (function) does the error rises?

Comment: I now see that you put the error message as a comment in the code sample. That is not very visible to us. The full traceback *separately* would have informed us more quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you have something like:

```
if hitChance() == True:
```

it needs to be:

```
if self.hitChance() == True:
```

Just as you need an explicit `self` for member variables like `self._strength`, you need it for methods as well.

Comment: And omit the `== True`; it is redundant.

Comment: There are more method calls in `__str__` that have the same problem.

Comment: It was easy. And I apologize for being vague. Just trying to learn here.